# Filling up float ** from int16_t *

Tags: c, malloc

I need to convert a int16_t* in to an float **

I need them to pass through a function which requires and input buffer like:

```
const float * const * const buf,
```

Allocation of float**

```
  micsbuf = (float **)malloc(CHANNELS * sizeof(float *));
  farbuf = (float **)malloc(CHANNELS*sizeof(float *));
  for(int c1 = 0;c1 < CHANNELS;c1++)
  {
    micsbuf[c1] = (float *)malloc(BUFFER_LENGTH*sizeof(float));
    farbuf[c1] = (float *)malloc(BUFFER_LENGTH*sizeof(float));

  }
```

Rest of the code:

```
while(!feof(infile) || !feof(outfile))
  {
    NreadNear = fillBufferIn(infile, &bufferIn, bytes);
    NreadFar = fillBufferOut(outfile,&bufferOut,bytes);

    int16_t *bufferInCasted = (int16_t *)bufferIn;
    int16_t *bufferOutCasted = (int16_t *)bufferOut;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 480 ; i++)
    {
      for(int c2 = 0 ; c2 < CHANNELS ; c2 ++)
      {
        micsbuf[c2][i] = (float )bufferInCasted[i];
        micsbuf[c2][1+i*2] = (float )bufferInCasted[1+i*2];
        farbuf[c2][i] = (float )bufferOutCasted[i];
        farbuf[c2][1+i*2] = (float )bufferOutCasted[1+i*2];
      }
      printf("I:  %d\t", i);
      printf("Left Sample Near %d\t", bufferInCasted[i]);
      printf("Right Sample Near %d\t\t", bufferInCasted[1+i*2]);
      printf("Left Sample Far %d\t", bufferOutCasted[i]);
      printf("Right Sample Far %d\n\n", bufferOutCasted[1+i*2]);
    }
  }
```

The problem is that when I put through the function which requires it, that function results in Seg.Fault. It's proprietary library.

```
/**
 * @brief 
 * Should fill up the buffer;
 * @param mics 
 * @param bufferIn 
 * @return size_t 
 */ 
size_t fillBufferIn(FILE *in, void **buffer, size_t bytes) //1920 byte
{ 
  size_t Nread;
  /**
   * @brief 
   * Should return a buffer with float[][] so that it can read and write
   * Each time it read sizeof of two int16_t which are the left channel and right channel
   * 
   */
  *buffer = (void *)calloc(480,2*sizeof(int16_t));
  Nread = fread(*buffer, 2*sizeof(int16_t), 480, in);
  return 2*sizeof(int16_t)*Nread;
}

/**
 * @brief 
 * Should fill up the buffer
 * @param out 
 * @param bufferOut 
 * @param bytes 
 * @return size_t 
 */
size_t fillBufferOut(FILE *out, void **bufferOut, size_t bytes)
{
  *bufferOut = (void *)calloc(480,2*sizeof(int16_t));
  Nread = fread(*bufferOut, 2*sizeof(int16_t), 480, out);
  return 2*sizeof(int16_t)*Nread;
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/3684343

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: When I put through a function which uses it it results in seg.fault

Comment: Please make sure you've got a proper problem statement in your question. The `micsbuf[c2][1+i*2]` does not look right.

Comment: @GentBinaku So use a debugger to determine where the segfault occurs, examine values of variables around there, and determine what's wrong in the code.

Comment: Easier said than done

Comment: size of BUFFER_LENGTH?

Comment: Size of BUFFER_LENGTH 480

Comment: @GentBinaku did you check with gdb where exactly segfault is occurred?

Comment: Yes at the function which I call from the propitiatory library so I can't get enough info and that error

Comment: Are you sure that you not going out of bounds with `bufferInCasted[1+i*2];` in the function `fillBufferIn()` you `(void *)calloc(480,2*sizeof(int16_t));` its mean 480 elements for array with the size `2 * sizeof(int16_t)`

Comment: and then you try to do next `bufferInCasted[1+i*2]` which far out of 480 index

Comment: So each time around the `while` loop, you call `fillBufferIn` and `fillBufferOut` that allocate new buffers for `bufferIn` and `bufferOut`. But where do you free those buffers? At the moment it looks like a memory leak.

Comment: I don't think so about that cuz I read from the file, they should be written over

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `malloc`ed blocks for `micsbuf[c1]` and `farbuf[c1]` are only half the size they need to be. You need room for `BUFFER_LENGTH` left/right pairs of samples. Here is a corrected version:

   ```
     for(int c1 = 0;c1 < CHANNELS;c1++)
     {
        micsbuf[c1] = (float *)malloc(BUFFER_LENGTH*2*sizeof(float));
        farbuf[c1] = (float *)malloc(BUFFER_LENGTH*2*sizeof(float));

     }
   ```
2. The code for filling in and accessing the left/right pairs of samples is incorrect. It overwrites earlier samples and leaves some samples not filled in. The indices for the left channel should be changed from `i` to `i*2` so that they are just before the indices for the right channel `1+i*2`. Here is a corrected version:

   ```
       for(int i = 0 ; i < 480 ; i++)
       {
         for(int c2 = 0 ; c2 < CHANNELS ; c2 ++)
         {
           micsbuf[c2][i*2] = (float )bufferInCasted[i*2];
           micsbuf[c2][1+i*2] = (float )bufferInCasted[1+i*2];
           farbuf[c2][i*2] = (float )bufferOutCasted[i*2];
           farbuf[c2][1+i*2] = (float )bufferOutCasted[1+i*2];
         }
         printf("I:  %d\t", i);
         printf("Left Sample Near %d\t", bufferInCasted[i*2]);
         printf("Right Sample Near %d\t\t", bufferInCasted[1+i*2]);
         printf("Left Sample Far %d\t", bufferOutCasted[i*2]);
         printf("Right Sample Far %d\n\n", bufferOutCasted[1+i*2]);
       }
   ```

   You should also consider replacing the magic number `480` in the loop with `BUFFER_LENGTH` if that is correct, or some other symbolic constant.

Comment: Still the same result Seg.Fault

Comment: @GentBinaku Perhaps you also need to double the sizes of `bufferIn` and `bufferOut`?

Comment: I am working upon a platform which has a buffer 1920 bytes from it's audio source, and each 4 bytes represent a int16_t*, which means I have 480 left channel and 480  right channel in those bytes. So what bufferIn and bufferOut are void pointers to those memory addresses

Comment: @GentBinaku Each 4 bytes represents a `int16_t*`? Don't you mean it represents 2 `int16_t`s?

Comment: Yes that's exactly two channels

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line `micsbuf[c2][1+i*2] = (float )bufferInCasted[1+i*2];`. You allocate the sub array at `micsbuf`, a size `CHANNELS*sizeof(float *)` bytes, which is `CHANNELS*4`. And your i vary from 1 to 480. The `CHANNELS` variable should be high enough otherwise it will show the error, as you are trying to access the memory not allocated to that variable.

Comment: That's because I have two channels of audio signal, so it float[2][480] actually.
Each time I read 480*2*int16_t which is 1920 bytes