# Proprietary Library returns seg.fault

Tags: c, buffer

I have a proprietary library lets say libX.

libX is a Speech Recognition and has a function to write to a wav(In my case it's pcm).

The function let's libX write has this definition:

```
void Write
(
    FILE * const p,
    const float * const * const buffer,
    const float range,
    const size_t frameToBeWritten,
    size_t * const frameWritten
);
```

I have managed to fill a buffer which is float **, however I still get segmentation fault.

My question How would one go about fixing this problem.

I have a working example of this function, however that example doesn't do justice to the implementation,checked gdb with function PrintArray, since I investigated how the working example float ** is being filled :

```
void PrintArray(float ** a,int channels,int buffer_length){
      int i;
      int j; 
        for (i=0; i<channels; i++)
        {
            printf("===========================");
            printf("Channel %d \n",i);
            for (j=0; j<buffer_length; j++)
            {
                printf("%f  ", a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
}
```

In both my code and the example code, the arrays are being filled correctly
I couldn't find any differences betweem my float ** and the working example float **

For more code please refer to: [Filling up float ** from int16_t *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469537/filling-up-float-from-int16-t)

Comment: Using a VLA: `void PrintArray(int channels, int buffer_length, float (*a)[buffer_length]){` notice the order of the arguments changed.

Comment: I understand that, but this is trying to print out values I need to see how the buffer is being filled.

I didn't notice any differences between my buffer and the working example buffer

Comment: That `Write` API looks rather questionable. I wouldn't trust code written by people who spam pointless qualifiers all over the place, just because they can. This is _not_ proper const correctness, it's just obfuscation.